# Is there a way to point a function/statement to itself?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This isn't really a problem, more of just out of pure curiosity. 
I am brand new to python and have seen that compared to C++ or Java, this language is really simple, and has a lot of shortcuts.

So is there a way to point something to itself? Let me clarify. For example, the following line:

```py
line = line.lower()
```

Is there a way to not have the "line = " part? Is there a way to have the function/statement to modify itself and set it to the new value? My inspiration comes from the autofill text in pycharm that said

```
line.lower(self)
```

I doubt this is possible, but if anyone possibly knows a way, that would be pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-place operations are only possible for mutable objects like `list`. In Python, as in Java, strings are an immutable type. The operation `line.lower()` produces an entirely new and separate string object. Without the `something = ...` part, you would lose the reference to this new object, and `line` would happily go on being bound to the original uppercase string. If you reassign specifically to `line` rather than some other name, you will be rebinding that name to the new lowercased object. In CPython, that means that you will decrement the reference counter of the original line, and possibly garbage collect it.

That being said, there's nothing stopping you from writing a class that behaves as you want. It can be made mutable by maintaining an internal reference to a string. By implementing the correct dunder methods, you can simulate the entire interface of `str`. Here is a partial toy example to get you started:

```
class MyStr:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    def __add__(self, s):
        return MyStr(self.s + str(s))

    def __iadd__(self, s):
        self.s += str(s)
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return self.s

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(type(self).__name__, self.s)

    def lower(self):
        return MyStr(self.s.lower())

    def ilower(self):
        self.s = self.s.lower()

    ...
```